# WHMCS - Different currency billing per order for a single client

Tags: php, whmcs

so my Q is:
**Currently i have only 1 default currency per client, while i need several billing currencies for its orders** (Choose the order currency at the 'New Order' tab instead of choosing a default currency at the client's profile)

Is there any way to do it without getting in the code and making a new template for it? (some module addon for example).
If not, is there any specific tutorial on how should i a custom  field and connect its chosen data to the invoice and  change it accordingly?

**Any help will be highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

At a database level, there's only one currency set for the client in tblclients. tblinvoices doesn't mention currency in any way. Therefor, it is impossible to have different invoices or even invoice lines having stated amounts in different currencies.

When you change the currency at client level, you'll even notice that all existing invoices have changed from one currency to the other. You'll really need to have something built custom, but even then, I doubt that it will work, since this currency thing is designed to popup everywhere in standard code both client and admin side.